# Construct an example with given properties, otherwise disprove it

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $0<a<1$ be fixed, does there exist a (piecewise) $C^1$ function $f$ over $x\in (0,1/2)$ with the following properties simultaneously fufilled
$$f(x)>0, f'(x)>0, \left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)'\leq0, f(x)\sim x (x\rightarrow 0^+)$$ and satisfies the differential inequality $$xf'(x)\leq a f(x), \forall x\in (0,1/2)$$

Note: I attempted to consider examples of the form $f(x)=1-\exp(-2bx)$ where $b>0$ is fixed, but one can show that $f$ is strictly monotone over $(0,1/2]$ with $f(0^+)=1$, and thus such form of $f$ does not fufill the condition $0<a<1$. I also tried to assume the form $f(x)=x+x^{p}$ with $p>1$ fixed, and it turns out one also needs $a\geq 1$ to make it work, which is not allowed.

Comment: If $f(x)/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0^+,$ then choose $a<b<1$ and we have $f'(x)\le b$ for small $x.$ This contradicts $f(x)/x\to 1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not exist any function $f$ with the given properties.
Proof: the differential inequality is equivalent to $$(x^{-a}f(x))'\leq 0,~\forall 0<x<1/2.$$

Since $f(x)\sim x ~(x\rightarrow 0^+)$ and $0<a<1$, we have $$(x^{-a}f(x))'\sim (x^{1-a})'=(1-a)x^{-a}>0 ~(x\rightarrow 0^+),$$ which contradicts to the differential inequality near a neibourhood of $0^+$.